# Typewriter script bug

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, settimeout

I have a problem. What's wrong with this script, why does one letter appear and disappear when its resetting message? How to fix it?
[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaYVza)

```js
var i = 0;
var msgnow = 0;
var msg = ["Wiadomość 1", "Wiadomość 2", "Wiadomość 3"]; //message 1, 2, 3
var speed = 100;

function writeMessage() {
  setTimeout(writeMessage, speed);

  if (i < msg[msgnow].length) {
    document.getElementById("messagebar").innerHTML += msg[msgnow].charAt(i);
    i++;
  } else {
    setTimeout(resetMessages, 3000);
  }
}

function resetMessages() {
  document.getElementById("messagebar").innerHTML = "";
  msgnow++;
  i = 0;
  if (msgnow == msg.length) {
    msgnow = 0;
  }
}

writeMessage();
```

```html
<span id="messagebar"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `writeMessage` function is immediately (and always) creating a new timeout with no regard for how far along the previous timeout is or if there is a reset pending.

Try to have only 1 timeout going at a time.  Additionally, you should encapsulate the typing into its own scope so that you don't have those global variables.

Consider the changes below:

```js
var i = 0;
var msgnow = 0;
var msg = ["Wiadomość 1", "Wiadomość 2", "Wiadomość 3"]; //message 1, 2, 3
var speed = 100;
var messagebar = document.getElementById("messagebar");

function writeMessage() {
  if (i < msg[msgnow].length) {
    messagebar.innerHTML += msg[msgnow].charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(writeMessage, speed);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resetMessages();
      setTimeout(writeMessage, speed);
    }, 3000);
  }

}

function resetMessages() {
  messagebar.innerHTML = "";
  msgnow++;
  i = 0;
  if (msgnow == msg.length) {
    msgnow = 0;
  }
}

writeMessage();
```

```html
<span id="messagebar"></span>
```

---

Here is my solution using `async`/`await` :

```js
function $timeout(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), delay);
  });
}

async function wr(el, word) {
  if (typeof word !== "string") throw new Error("Must provide a String");

  el.innerHTML = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    el.innerHTML += word[i];
    await $timeout(100);
  }

}

(async function() {
  const typewriterEl = document.getElementById("typewriter");
  await wr(typewriterEl, "hello world");
  await $timeout(1000);
  await wr(typewriterEl, "fizz buzz");
}());
```

```html
<div id="typewriter"></div>
```